# how can I create an animated, labeled point following a trajectory in gnuplot?

Tags: animation, gnuplot

After quite a bit of tweaking to an existing GNU plot, I managed to get the following:

```
reset

# png
set terminal png size 350,262 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'

# color definitions
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 2 # --- blue

unset key
set border 0
unset tics
# set view 342,0
set xrange [-300:300]
set yrange [-300:300]

n=0
do for [ii=1:99] {
    n=n+1
    set output sprintf('png/spiral%03.0f.png',n)
    plot '1_1910.txt' every ::1::ii w l ls 1, \
   '2_1910.txt' every ::1::ii w l ls 1
}

do for [ii=1:99] {
    n=n+1
    set output sprintf('png/spiral1%03.0f.png',n)
     plot '1_1920.txt' every ::1::ii w l ls 1, \
    '2_1920.txt' every ::1::ii w l ls 1
 }
```

The idea is to create a set of PNG files, and then concatenate them all with animation.

I concatenate them all together using

```
  convert -delay 2 -loop 0 png/*.png animation.gif
```

I want to make more tweaks:

1. I don't want to keep the line that follows the whole plot (even though animated). Instead, I want a "bullet point" (maybe the size of 5-10 pixels) with text moving next to it for each frame for each data point in the plot.
2. I want a text at the bottom right for the first set of frames (in the first 1:99 loop) and a different text replacing it, again in the bottom right corner (in the next 1:99 loop).

My code is based on this:

http://www.gnuplotting.org/animation-iv-trajectory/

but I can't figure out why his code has a "trail" that disappears, and why he has also a bullet point and I don't. As I said, I also want text that moves with the bullet point (same text for each data file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with loops like this:

```
n = 0
do for [ii=0:60] {
    n=n+1
    set output sprintf('png/spiral%03.0f.png',n)
    plot 'data.dat' every ::ii::ii w p ls 1, \
   'data.dat' using 1:2:("foo") every ::ii::ii w labels offset 2
}

set label 1 "hyde" at 275,-275

do for [ii=60:0:-1] {
    n=n+1
    set output sprintf('png/spiral%03.0f.png',n)
    plot 'data.dat' every ::ii::ii w p ls 1, \
   'data.dat' using 1:2:("foo") every ::ii::ii w labels offset 2
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

You can play with the `offset` coordinates to position the label text `"foo"` where you want.

To change the size of the point, change the value of `ps` in the line style command at the beginning of your script.

I am not sure what the purpose of the two different files is (1_1910.txt and 2_1920.txt), so I used the same file in my example. You may need to add to the plot command if you are plotting two different things at once.

As for your other questions, I think looking closely at the code in the [example](http://www.gnuplotting.org/code/spiral.gnu) should give you an idea of what is going on. In the example, the range `every ::1::ii` plots points from `1` to `ii`, giving a line; the range `every ::ii::ii` plots just one point. Note that the abbreviations `w l` and `w p` in the example expand to `with lines` and `with points`, respectively.

In the example the line disappears due to the action of the second loop, which runs in reverse (`for [ii=99:1:-1]`). If you are copying that example, make sure also that your indices run over the correct values (you may have a number other than 99 of data points). Also note that indices in gnuplot start at 0, so if the first line of your data file contains data (not a header) you want to start your loop at `ii=0` instead of `ii=1`.

Comment: I do need to plot two files in parallel, but for some reason when I add another file (two additional exact statements to each plot, just with a different file name), I get an error. that doesn't happen with the original code - I can add as many files as I want. any ideas why?

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing some of the code, or at least an error message/description of what goes wrong. Your code might have the wrong continuation syntax--`, \` at the end of the plot line, followed by the filename (no `plot` keyword) at the beginning of the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I am having nearly the same problem here. I found a really nice hack! Instead of making multiple png's and then merge them, you just use `set multiplot` and then `unset multiplot` inside ONE loop. Being specific I used it this way:

```
do for [i=0:k] 

{    

    set multiplot 

    plot function1  
    plot function2    
    unset multiplot 

}
```

But unfortunately this won't work unless the data set you have is synchronized!, but yet can be solve this using if-statement!. Good Luck